# Variable name cannot be resolved to a variable - I cannot locate the problem

Tags: java, eclipse, nodes

On line 110, where it says "return front3" I get this error. I'm not sure why, I create the Node front3 inside the while loop.

```
    public static Node add(Node poly1, Node poly2) {
        /** COMPLETE THIS METHOD **/
        // FOLLOWING LINE IS A PLACEHOLDER TO MAKE THIS METHOD COMPILE
        // CHANGE IT AS NEEDED FOR YOUR IMPLEMENTATION
        Node ptr1 = poly1;
        Node ptr2 = poly2;
        Node ptr3 = null;
        // Node front3;

        while (ptr1 != null && ptr2 != null) {
            if (ptr1.term.degree == ptr2.term.degree) {
                if (ptr3 == null) {
                    Node front3 = new Node(ptr1.term.coeff + ptr2.term.coeff,ptr1.term.degree,null);
                    ptr3 = front3;
                } else {
                    Node temp = new Node(ptr1.term.coeff + ptr2.term.coeff,ptr1.term.degree,null);
                    ptr3.next = temp;
                    ptr3 = temp;
                }
                ptr1 = ptr1.next;
                ptr2 = ptr2.next;
            } else if ( ptr1.term.degree > ptr2.term.degree) {
                if (ptr3 == null) {
                    Node front3 = new Node(ptr1.term.coeff,ptr1.term.degree,null);
                    ptr3 = front3;
                } else {
                    Node temp = new Node(ptr1.term.coeff, ptr1.term.degree , null);
                    ptr3.next = temp;
                    ptr3 = temp;
                }
                ptr1 = ptr1.next;
            } else if ( ptr1.term.degree < ptr2.term.degree ) {
                if (ptr3 == null) {
                    Node front3 = new Node(ptr2.term.coeff, ptr2.term.degree,null);
                    ptr3 = front3;
                } else {
                    Node temp = new Node(ptr2.term.coeff,ptr2.term.degree,null);
                    ptr3.next = temp;
                    ptr3 = temp;
                }
                ptr2 = ptr2.next;
            }
        }


        if (ptr3 == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return front3;
    }
```

I then created a different Node, Node front4, initialized it to something and my program ran. This was done OUTSIDE the while loop.

Comment: And what should happen if you don't enter the while loop!?

Comment: Don't you want `return ptr3;`?

Comment: Thats why I created the if statement, if the while loop is never used, then ptr 3 = null, and null will be returned, am I missing something? @B.Go

Comment: No, I created that if statement just incase the while loop never executed, so that null will be returned before the program goes to the line where front3 is returned because front3 wouldn't have been created

Answer (score 1):

It happens because objects only exist inside the block they are declared. In your case, your `front3` will only exist inside the `if` block you used to declare it:

```
if (ptr3 == null) {
    Node front3 = new Node(ptr2.term.coeff, ptr2.term.degree,null);
    ptr3 = front3; // Can use it here
}
// Cannot use it here
```

If you really need to return the `front3` object you should declare it in the "method level", the same as you are doing for your `ptr` nodes. In fact, you already have it commented there. If you simply apply the changes as below you should be good to go:

Current:

```
// Node front3;
```

After:

```
Node front3 = null; // Needs to initialize
```

And your `if` statements should be changed as the example below:

Current:

```
if (ptr3 == null) {
    Node front3 = new Node(ptr1.term.coeff,ptr1.term.degree,null);
    ptr3 = front3;
}
```

After:

```
if (ptr3 == null) {
    front3 = new Node(ptr1.term.coeff,ptr1.term.degree,null); // No need for "Node", as it was already declared
    ptr3 = front3;
}
```

Ps. I didn't review the logic. This is just to explain why you are getting the *"Variable name cannot be resolved to a variable"* error.